# CORS Isuue if both url belong to same server

Tags: javascript, java, cors

I have two website abc.com and xyz.com both are running from same server so would i be getting any CORS issue? I think CORS issue comes only when we request from one server to another which has differ IPs. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

CORS is not caring about IP but domain. Because abc.com and xyz.com has a different domain, so they have CORS issue.